# Translating JSON into Twig Looping Arrays

Tags: arrays, json, loops, twig, counter

I'm new to JSON and Twig. I was able to convert the basic items from JSON to TWIG but when I got to the array parts, I got stuck. I have tried different types of things and have not been very successful. The first one is more complex:

[image: Complex JSON Array], so I have not done anything with that one yet (This is the code snippet so far trying to display something:

```
Freight List Item: <br>
Quantity: {{Result.FreightInformation.0.0.Item.Quantity}}<br>
Dim Type: {{Result.FreightInformation.0.0.Item.DimType}}<br>
Units: {{Result.FreightInformation.Item.0.0.Units}}<br>
Commodity: {{Result.FreightInformation.I0.0.tem.Commodity}}<br>
Weight: {{Result.FreightInformation.Item.0.0.Weight}}<br>
Length: {{Result.FreightInformation.Item.0.0.Length}}<br>
Width: {{Result.FreightInformation.Item.0.0.Width}}<br>
Height: {{Result.FreightInformation.Item.0.0.Height}}<br>
Class: {{Result.FreightInformation.Item.0.0.Class}}<br>
NMFC: {{Result.FreightInformation.Item.0.0.NMFC}}<br>
Hazmat: {{Result.FreightInformation.Item.0.0.Hazmat}}<br>
<br>
```

The second one less complex (so I tried my hand on that one) but there are quite a few items that have been looped through:
[image: Basic JSON Array]

I have been researching but I am at a point where I need to expedite this since the individual waiting for me to complete this taks will be testing their patience.

```
Tracking Information<br>

{% for Result.TrackingInformation in Result.TrackingInformation %}
  {% set counter = ( counter | default(0) ) + 1 %}
  <p>{{ counter ~ ' ). ' Result.TrackingInformation.i.Item }}</p>
Person: {% for i in 0..100 %} {{Result.TrackingInformation.i.Item.Person}} {% endfor %}<br>
Code: {% for i in 0..100 %} {{Result.TrackingInformation.i.Item.Code}} {% endfor %}<br>
Status: {% for i in 0..100 %} {{Result.TrackingInformation.i.Item.Status}} {% endfor %}<br>
Remarks: {% for i in 0..100 %} {{Result.TrackingInformation.i.Item.Remarks}} {% endfor %}<br>
Date: {% for i in 0..100 %} {{Result.TrackingInformation.i.Item.date}} {% endfor %}<br>
Time:{% for i in 0..100 %} {{Result.TrackingInformation.i.Item.time}} {% endfor %}<br>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna break this answer in two parts, reflecting both snippet

**Snippet 1**

I would assume the snippet you wrote here is correct, however `twig` is not having this notation and throws a weird error

> Key "Item" for array with keys "0" does not exist.

I've opened a [ticket](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/3549) about this behaviour on GitHub as I can't my head around this issue, as I'd expect the correct result.

---

**edit**

So the reason the dot notation doesn't work is because the `0.0` part is getting parsed as a float, so the only way to access these values is with the array notation - [source](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/3549#issuecomment-885537340)

---

However you can also use the array notation in `twig` to get the correct output here

```html
{{ Result.FreightInformation[0][0].Item.Quantity }}
```

**Snippet 2**

In this part you are trying to use a variable to fetch the correct index from the array. However for this snippet you **cannot** use the dot notation, as `twig` would interpret the following snippet as `i` being an index of the array, it will not interpolate the `i` to it's current value

```html
{{Result.TrackingInformation.i.Item.Person}}
```

In short, `twig` would compile this to `$Result['TrackingInformation']['i']['Item']['Person']`

You have two solutions to fix this issue

1. Use the array notation as well

```html
{{Result.TrackingInformation[i].Item.Person}}
```

2. Use the [attribute function](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html)

```html
{{ attribute(Result.TrackingInformation, i).Item.Person}}
```

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful information. The data is showing now. I am trying to list them so that each tracking item lists in a group of their own (like shown in the JSON file) Right now it is displaying like this: Person: Auto Tracker. Auto Tracker Auto Tracker Auto Tracker. Auto Tracker. Auto Tracker. Auto Tracker. Auto Tracker. Auto Tracker. Auto Tracker. Auto Tracker Auto Tracker. Auto Tracker. Auto

Comment: Right now it is displaying like this: <a href="https://i52.683.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Screen-Shot-2021-07-23-at-15.34.25.png">Not correct</a>but needs to display something like this: <a href="https://i52.683.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Screen-Shot-2021-07-23-at-15.38.47.png">Correct View</a>(I can make it look good later)